# Removing object element from array of object in state (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to remove an object from my array but it always removes the last one.

```
const removeDuplicateHandler = (id) => {
    setCopyActions((copyActions) =>
      copyActions.filter((action) => action.id !== id)
    );
};
```

And this is the loop that Im running through

```
{copyActions.map((actionType, idx) => (
        <TargetInputBox
          key={idx}
          isDuplicate={true}
          actionName={actionType.label}
          contactPersons={store.allContactPersons}
          buttonAttrValue={actionType.value}
          duplicateAddHandler={() =>
            addDuplicateHandler(actionType.value, actionType.label)
          }
          duplicateRemoveHandler={() =>
            removeDuplicateHandler(actionType.id)
          }
        />
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop is a better and more efficient way to do this:

```
const duplicate = [...copyActions]
for (let i = 0; i < copyActions.length; i++) {
    if (copyActions[i].id === id) {
        duplicate.splice(i, 1)
    }
    if (i + 1 === copyActions.length) {
        setCopyActions(duplicate)
    }
}
```

You create a duplicate of the array and loop through it. If the program finds an ID that is the same as `id`, it will remove that index from the array. Once the loop has finished, it will set the state to the altered array.